# How to handle same multiple request in multiple servers

Tags: java, spring, microservices

I have an application running on microservice architecture where I have multiple dockers for the same application, now if a request comes it can go either to APP1 or APP2 (assume there are only two instances of the same application), both APPs have the fund deduction method lets suppose api/deduct/10.

let's Suppose this API is exposed to outer word its bank's API which any application can use, let's suppose a person is ordering something from Website1 which integrated with the Bank and at the same time he/she is ordering from Website2 which is also integrated with the same Bank.

now let's suppose he/she have only $10 in the account and both websites are trying to deduct money from the bank. this is the microservice architecture both requests can land on different servers then how it will be handled?

How the application can ensure that it handles the negative balance in this case.

Comment: I'd start with the API design - `api/deduct/10` does not sound like an appropriate RESTful endpoint but more like an RPC. Correct implementation of REST should be different from RPC

Comment: Sorry, It was just an example I have a proper design for the REST APIs endpoint

Comment: can you elaborate more? i don't get the point of handling negative balance. is it single user sending two  requests?  if explain complete scenario it's easier to understand

Comment: I have a central system API which takes userid and amount to deduct, now any one who has access to this api can call this method, lets suppose we have a customer who is trying to do the payment in two different sites which are internally using my central system to access his account. in this case how do we handle the suffient balance case in a effective way, I could acquire a lock on userid but its not the effient way.